# How to add a CDATA content to an existing XML in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I tried to google it, but guess I'm the first person regarding this question anywhere ;) I found `StreamingMarkupBuilder` but this is mainly used to create a new XML which I do not need. And I couldn't figure out how to add and not create.

So I have my pretty XML:

```
<root>
  <ducks>
    <rubberduck />
  </ducks>
</root>
```

and all I want is to add a `CDATA` for my rubberducky:

```
<root>
  <ducks>
    <rubberduck><![CDATA[Best Duck Ever!]]></rubberduck>
  </ducks>
</root>
```

First I used `XmlSlurper` and `replaceBody` but this will espace the `CDATA`-tag.

So how I can I simply add a CDATA in Groovy, which is required in my request for to a webservice? In Java I would just use

`ducksNode.appendChild(rootDoc.createCDATASection("...."))`

I was getting used to Groovy being easier and faster than Java.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do anything that you can do in Java also in Groovy more or less the same way at least.

But why do you need to make it a `CDATA` section? Just set the text and Groovy will escape the characters that need escaping automatically, which makes the `CDATA` section obsolete.

Comment: It's a request for a webservice and the webservice expects the data in an CDATA sections unfortunately. I guess I have to use Java then, I just could not believe that quick-and-easy groovy is uncapable of such a simple task.

Comment: Because it is totally unnecessary. A CDATA section has to be transparent. It must not make any difference whether you have a CDATA section or accordingly quoted content. iirc even if you parse an XML and write it out unchanged with Java, the CDATA sections will be gone, as it is exactly the same if done right.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder` with `mkp.yieldUnescaped`:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def sw = new StringWriter()
def builder = new MarkupBuilder(sw)

builder.root {
    ducks {
        rubberduck {
            mkp.yieldUnescaped("<![CDATA[" + "Best Duck Ever!" + "]]>")
        }
    }
}

println sw.toString()
```

Comment: but thats exactly what I cannot use, you are rebuilding my XML, I have the XML already. Ofc ducks is just an example, it's much more complicated than that, and the effort to "rebuild" it, even though it exists already, is not worth it.